# Reading project parameters in Script Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

This is what I'm trying to do in a script task:

```
long lngMaxRowsToPull = Convert.ToInt64(Dts.Variables["Project::MaxRowsPerPull"].Value);
```

I get an error message that the variable does not exist.

Yet Its defined as a ReadOnlyVariable to the script and it does exist as a project parameter.

[image: Its defined as a ReadOnlyVariable to the script]

[image: And it does exist as a project parameter]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So close. ;)

Your code is trying to access a variable/parameter named `Project::MaxRowsPerPull`

In fact, the $ is significant so you need to reference `$Project::MaxRowsPerPull`

Also note that you have the data type for the parameter as Int32 but are then pushing it into Int64. You can always put a smaller type into a larger container but if you tried to fill the parameter with too large a value your package will asplode.

Comment: thanks, looking at it and not seeing it! I did notice the type discrepancy as I was writing this post and fixed it already. ))

Comment: For what it's worth, this will work in Script Tasks, *but not if they are inside Package Parts*; in that case, create a variable name inside the Package Part, re-scope it to the Package once inside the Package, and then add this an expression `@[$Project::MaxRowsPerPull]` to the re-scoped variable.

Comment: @codeMonkey Does *anything* work well with package parts </sadtrombone>

Answer (score 1):

You need to add $ to your parameter fetch name as per syntax.

```
long lngMaxRowsToPull = Convert.ToInt64(Dts.Variables["$Project::MaxRowsPerPull"].Value);
```

Comment: It would help if you added some descriptive text explaining what about your code solves the problem and why. Thanks!